Getting Internet from Layer 2 Bridge
I have 64-bit Ubuntu 23.10 Server running on a Raspberry Pi 4B. The Pi has a separate USB WiFi dongle (wlx00c0cab46ac3) that allows for 4addr mode, and I'd like to use this dongle to create a Layer 2 WiFi to Ethernet Bridge. I've successfully created the bridge and saved the configuration to a yaml file, but the bridge itself does not have an inet IP address and thus no network connection. I'm wondering if anyone knows what has to be done next to get my WiFi adapter to connect to the internet and give this connection to an ethernet client. I've tried:
1)connecting the USB-WIFi dongle to WiFi, enabling 4addr mode, then adding it to the bridge.
2) Creating the bridge first, enabling 4addr mode on the dongle, then trying to connect the USB-WiFi dongle to my network.
when running brctl show I'm able to see br0 with STP enabled, and both Ethernet and WiFi interfaces listed. So I know most of what I'm trying to accomplish is working, just can't get the extra step of having the bridge retrieve it's internet connection from the USB-WiFi dongle. Does anyone have any tips? I've attached a picture of my yaml file for reference, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
yaml bridge file

ip -a output

